# Draw on a image in a precise position on the screen.

Tags: android, image, layout, draw

I'm trying to draw a point in a map. I'm detecting the position of some objects, and then displaying a map to the user, where, he can see the position of the objects on the map.

For example if I work with a grid, i know that the first object has the coordinates (1,3) and the second one has the coordinates (4,5). How can I put these object in the image if I know the scale of the image ?

I would like to have a result similar to the given picture, i mean drawing in an image :(This is a screen shot from inseteo application )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try opensource lib [ImageLayout](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/ImageLayout)

*A layout that arranges its children in relation to a background image.*

Example code snippet.Full example project is in git repo of ImageLayout.

```
Button button = new Button(this);
        ImageLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ImageLayout.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.left = 243;
        layoutParams.top = 297;
        layoutParams.right = 432;
        layoutParams.bottom = 405;
        button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.normal_text));
        button.setText(R.string.harlem);
        imageLayout.addView(button, layoutParams);
```

[Link to demo activity code](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/ImageLayout/blob/master/sample/src/com/manuelpeinado/imagelayout/demo/ChangeImageDynamicallyActivity.java)

Comment: OK Thank you @Adhikari Bishwash . I'm trying it now.

Comment: how can i use it ?i'm little bit lost ,what i have to import in my app ?

Comment: as the lib is using gradle build, if you are using eclipse then you need to convert it to eclipse project and import it as library to your project.

Comment: So i have to convert library folder to an android project ? @Adhikari Bishwash

Comment: It is android project but using gradle build.

Comment: Try downloading lib and import its library folder as android source in eclipse (This may work).

Comment: Do i have to do those steps in this link [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54105/discussion-between-adhikari-bishwash-and-amina).